# Subtree of Another Tree Complexity Analysis

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

On Leetcode, Question [#572](https://leetcode.com/problems/subtree-of-another-tree/description/) prompts the user to check whether a particular tree (given by its root) is a subtree of another tree (given by its root). Below is an implementation to solve this problem:

```
class Solution:
    def isSubtree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], subRoot: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        def isSameTree(p, q):
            if not p and not q:
                return True
            if not p or not q or p.val != q.val:
                return False
            
            return isSameTree(p.left, q.left) and isSameTree(p.right, q.right)
        
        def recurse(root, subRoot):
            if not root:
                return False
            elif isSameTree(root, subRoot):
                return True
        
            return recurse(root.right, subRoot) or recurse(root.left, subRoot)
        
        return recurse(root, subRoot)
```

In effect, the `recurse()` call will be called once for each node in the parent tree. During a given call, `iSameTree()` will be called an attempt to "super-impose" the subtree onto the tree, starting at the current node. If it can successfully match all components of the subtree, then `iSameTree()` will return `True`. Otherwise, it will return `False`.

While the implementation is a form of brute force, I am having a harder time discussing time and space complexity. For the intent of analysis, let us say that the size of the potential parent tree in nodes is given by `N` whereas the size of the potential subtree in nodes is given by `M`.

When it comes to time complexity, we could quickly conclude that there will be `N` calls to `recurse()`, with *each* having the potential to generate a maximum of `M` calls to `isSameTree()`. Therefore, at worst, there will be `N*M` total calls. Apart from the recursive component, each function call takes constant time to perform, so we can say that this algorithm is worst-case O(NM). While this makes sense, I feel as though there may be a tighter bound. In other words, for an arbitrary `N` node parent tree and `M` node subtree, it will be impossible for every one of the `N` `recurse()` calls to lead to `M` `IsSubtree()` calls; for instance, leaf nodes will naturally terminate after the first `IsSameTree()` call; so, if `M` is not size 1, then the `recurse()` calls associated with leaf nodes will result in fewer than M calls in every other scenario. I say all of this to ask: Is there a way to find a tighter bound?

When it comes to auxiliary space complexity, it is perhaps even more complicated. Some folks are quick to assert that the space complexity is `O(LogN + LogM)`, but, again, this does not make sense to me. Moreover, at any given time, we can have a maximum of `LogN` `recurse()` calls on the call stack. At any given time, we can also have a maximum of `LogM` `isSameTree()` calls on the call stack. While these two statements are true, they are never *simultaneously* true for an arbitrary `N` and `M`. That is, to achieve `LogM` `isSameTree()` calls on the call stack, the most recent `recurse()` call needs to be on a node that is at least `LogM` levels from the leaf nodes in the parent tree; therefore, the deepest level that the node can be is `LogN - LogM`. It follows that there can only be `LogN - LogM` `recurse()` calls and `LogM` `isSameTree` calls on the call stack at a given time; in total, that is `LogN` calls. On the flip side, for there to be `LogN` `recurse()` calls on the call stack, the most recent call to `recurse()` needs to be on a leaf node in the parent tree. In such a case, this `recurse()` call can only lead to, at most, 2 `IsSubtree()` additional calls on the call stack. Based on this logic, then, the auxiliary space is simply `O(LogN)`. I say all of this to ask: is auxiliary space `O(LogN)` or `O(LogN + LogM)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis is easier than you think, because the worst case inputs (for both time and space) are completely unbalanced trees, i.e., linked lists, with all values the same.

Worst case time complexity is Θ(NM).  When M=N/2, for example, you will do N/2 comparisons of size M, and NM/2 is in Ω(NM).

Worst case space complexity is Θ(N).  You'll never recurse deeper than depth N, and you will get to depth N no matter what M is.

You can make a simple linear time algorithm by only comparing the subtree-to-find with subtrees of the same height.